# Regex, get only words from last piece of an URL

Tags: python-3.x, regex, string, url

I'm practicing with Regex module in python and i've met a difficulty. I managed to exctract only words from the last piece of URL string and excluding the format type like .pdf,.jpg, etc...  For example :

*first-second-third.pdf*

to receiving only "first","second","third".

I've used pattern like these:

```
pattern1=re.compile(r"(?<!\.)\b\w+")
pattern2=re.compile(r"(?<!\.)\b[a-z]+")
```

These patterns work well for previous URL example but they don't for URls like these:

*first_second_third.pdf*

*first%20second%20third.pdf*

To find all words i use :

`matching=re.findall(pattern1or2,url)`

So the problems are the characters like "_" or "%20" which are inclused in my matching.
Some tips ? thank you so much.

EDIT: i've not expressed well. I meant last part of an URL that identifies the format of hypothetical file.

Comment: First off, you're not going to find spaces (`%20`) in domain names...

Comment: Thanks for your understanding mr. @MattDMo. Your humorous comment will be very useful for my purpose :)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not make use of the word boundary because in this string `first_second_third.pdf` there is no word boundary between the `_` and the following `s` and `t`

You could use the character class `[a-z]+` to match lowercase chars only, asserting what is directly to the left is not a dot or a lowercase char a-z to prevent partial matches.

Use a positive lookahead to assert that the string ends with a dot and for example 1 or more word characters.

```
(?<![.a-z])[a-z]+(?=.*\.\w+$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ifVkSL/1)

Comment: I know i shouldnt add a comment to say thanks, but you have been gentleman. Thank you very much.